# Unable to pull Custom Dimension for a specific ID using BigQuery Standard SQL

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I came across a case where I could see value for CustomDimension1 in GA for a specific ID (CustomDimension 2). But when I pull the value from BigQuery using Standard SQL, I couldn't find the value, instead it is showing null value.

```
SELECT fullVisitorId, CD1, CD2
FROM (
  SELECT
    fullvisitorid, 
    (SELECT MAX(IF(index=1, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS CD1,
    (SELECT MAX(IF(index=2, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS CD2
  FROM `XXXXXXXXXXXXX`, UNNEST(hits) AS hits
)
WHERE CD2= '111111' and CD1 IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: remove `and CD1 is not null` from where clause - the rest of query looks good to me - but definitely is subject of what exactly your logic is

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant thanks for responding. When I remove 'CD1 is not null' I could see only null values. When it comes to logic, I am looking for a CD1 value for a specific CD2 ID which I could see in Google Analytics and it is not a null value.

Comment: replace MIN with MAX

Comment: Still no luck? I suggest you to provide good example of data showing your problem! I suspect your data is not what you expect, thus mulls

Comment: I meant `thus nulls` :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `MAX(IF(...))` trick in standard sql, simply use a sub-select in your `SELECT` statement - something like `(SELECT value FROM UNNEST(customDimensions) WHERE index=1) AS cd1` or in your specific case

```
SELECT
  fullvisitorid, visitstarttime, hitnumber,
  (SELECT cd.value
   FROM h.customDimensions AS cd
   WHERE cd.index=16 ) AS hitsCd2
FROM
  `project.dataset.ga_sessions_20171210` AS t, t.hits as h -- flatten to hits scope with cross join
LIMIT
  1000
```

The general approach is: First flatten to your desired dimension scope, in this case hits scope. Then calculate all the metrics - sub-selects for lower scopes and count(distinct some_id) for higher scopes.